# Rails: is there a way to tell the source of the request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, http-headers, xmlhttprequest, request

Google analytics tells me what the source of my traffic is (search engines, facebook etc). Is there a way to get this information for each request from the `request` object or otherwise? I'd appreciate any help.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`request.referrer` will give you the [HTTP referrer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) value.

Comment: This can be spoofed