# How I can understand from which URL the request came to the controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I tried to watch,

```
request.path_parameters
```

but its not bring any result. I would be grateful for any advice

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Rails: is there a way to tell the source of the request?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6366935/rails-is-there-a-way-to-tell-the-source-of-the-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [original_url](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-original_url)
>
> Returns the original request URL as a String.
>
> ```
> # get "/articles?page=2"
> request.original_url # => "http://www.example.com/articles?page=2"
> ```

Unless your asking about the [referer header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer) which can contain the URL that linked / redirected to your site. Which you can get through `request.referer`. But there is no real guarantee that the referer header is sent by the client.

Comment: shure, you answer is better

Answer (score 0):

request.referer

Sorry for the carelessness, I hope someone comes in handy